# Routes library for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, routes, porting

Can somebody skilled look at Routes library in python and tell me why there is not python 3 support?
I need Routes functionality for use with Cherrypy on python 3. And I am curious if it will be better to try to port Routes to python 3 or write my own dispatcher for python 3 from scratch.

I know some porting basics for python 2to3, but if there are any significant problems or drawbacks (other than method names, syntax etc), I would like to know them before I start working on the port.

Thank you very much for any tips!

Edit: 
do not understand me incorrectly! I am not lazy to check it by myself, but there are some aspects that i will not discover until I try it. And maybe, somebody here tried it before :-)

Comment: An obvious pitfall to check would be if `Routes` relies on any packages that aren't available in Python 3.

Comment: It looks like it's not updated much now (no commits for a couple of months). It's medium size (a couple of thousand lines). If you need a lot of its functionality, it will be quicker to port it than to start from scratch. If you only need small parts, there might be a smaller alternative you can drop in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to port Routes to python 3. 
After one day of work, I got all unit tests passed. But the code started being ugly and I was not sucessfull with using ported Routes with Cherrypy (probably something, that is not covered by unit tests). I was not patient enough to debug it.

So I decided to write my own version which I will maybe share as opensource. It is not ready yet and I will update this answer later (for possibly interested people :-)

Thanks to commenters above

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's not ready yet, publish it. I need it asap =) and i will improve it! Just do it!

Comment: @Dima hi, please contact me at joshuaboshi@gmail.com, we can discuss it :-)